# DataFrame running count and concatenation

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame which has 2 columns:

```
    part    content
0   'ok'    'A'
1   'ok'    'B'
2   ''      'C'
3   ''      'D'
4   ''      'E'
5   ''      'F'
6   'ok'    'G'
7   'ok'    'H'
8   ''      'I'
9   'ok'    'J'
10  ''      'K'
11  'ok'    'L'
12  ''      'M'
13  'ok'    'N'
14  ''      'O'
15  ''      'P'
```

I need to create new columns:

1. `count` - counter of items in one group

   - `if part == 'ok'`  then is first element of a group
   - `if part == ''` then it is part of a group above
2. `concat` - concatenation of items within one group
3. `take` - last row in a group, one with all items

It should look like below:

```
        part    content  count  concat    take
    0   'ok'    'A'      1      'A'       True
    1   'ok'    'B'      1      'B'       False
    2   ''      'C'      2      'BC'      False
    3   ''      'D'      3      'BCD'     False
    4   ''      'E'      4      'BCDE'    False
    5   ''      'F'      5      'BCDEF'   True
    6   'ok'    'G'      1      'G'       True
    7   'ok'    'H'      1      'H'       False
    8   ''      'I'      2      'HI'      True
    9   'ok'    'J'      1      'J'       False
    10  ''      'K'      2      'JK'      True
    11  'ok'    'L'      1      'L'       False
    12  ''      'M'      2      'LM'      True
    13  'ok'    'N'      1      'N'       False
    14  ''      'O'      2      'NO'      False
    15  ''      'P'      3      'NOP'     True
```

Then I will filter it to include only complete rows.

```
    concat
0   'A'
1   'BCDEF'
2   'G'
3   'HI'
4   'JK'
5   'LM'
6   'NOP'
```

I need help with the first part - how to create columns with running count, concatenation and True/False for the last row in a group.

**Also - data in above example is anonymized:**

- column `part` has 11 different elements to classify what part of content it is. Not just `ok` or `''`
- column `content` has one line of a document I am analyzing. It is a string of 0-400 characters.

Comment: Could you post what you have tired so far?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ummm, this question include three sub-questions q1 is use the `cumsum` create the group key then `cumcount` , q2 is `cumsum` , q3 is to get the max of each sub-group's position , so we `transform` `max`

```
df['count']=df.groupby(df.part.eq('ok').cumsum()).cumcount()+1
df['concat']=df.groupby(df.part.eq('ok').cumsum()).content.apply(lambda x : x.cumsum())
df['take']=df['count']==df.groupby(df.part.eq('ok').cumsum())['count'].transform('max')
df

   part content  count concat   take
0    ok       A      1      A   True
1    ok       B      1      B  False
2             C      2     BC  False
3             D      3    BCD  False
4             E      4   BCDE  False
5             F      5  BCDEF   True
6    ok       G      1      G   True
7    ok       H      1      H  False
8             I      2     HI   True
9    ok       J      1      J  False
10            K      2     JK   True
11   ok       L      1      L  False
12            M      2     LM   True
13   ok       N      1      N  False
14            O      2     NO  False
15            P      3    NOP   True
```

Comment: Thank you! I need to add one remark - this data is anonymized and column `part` has 11 different elements or ''. It should start counting whenever there is any element, not just 'ok', so `part.eq('ok')` wont work.

Comment: @BartekNowakowski change to part.ne('')

Comment: One more question, how to get concatenation with extra spaces between? It actually should be `B C D E F` instead of `BCDEF`.

Comment: @BartekNowakowski change the columns df['content ']=df['content ']+' '